# tornado: Recursion loop between websocket and iostream

Tags: recursion, websocket, tornado, zeromq

This is my first project using Tornado... building a message service 
with TornadIO + ZMQ. I'm using pyzmq's ioloop. 
I have been running into this issue of a recursive loop between the 
iostream and the websocket, and can't yet pinpoint why. Seems a client 
connects fine and sends plenty of messages and receives fine. Someone 
else connects and is fine for a bit then crash. I dont know if I'm not 
handling a disconnect properly, or if something in a message is 
causing a read error in the tornado code. All that is really happening in my server is that a client connects and sends messages, which then just get broadcasted to everyone else that is also connected via the websockets.

Maybe someone can tell me whats really happening here and if its something I'm not handling 
properly...

// Start of the traceback...

`[E 110426 01:45:28 ioloop:295] Exception in I/O handler for fd 22
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pyzmq-2.1.4-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 282, in start
        self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pyzmq-2.1.4-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/zmq/eventloop/stack_context.py", line 133, in wrapped
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 199, in _handle_events
        self._handle_read()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 258, in _handle_read
        if self._read_from_buffer():`

// START: block that loops recursively

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 325, in _read_from_buffer
        self._consume(loc + delimiter_len))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 230, in _run_callback
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/stack_context.py", line 173, in wrapped
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/websocket.py", line 193, in _on_end_delimiter
        self._receive_message()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/websocket.py", line 178, in _receive_message
        self.stream.read_bytes(1, self._on_frame_type)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 149, in read_bytes
        if self._read_from_buffer():
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 314, in _read_from_buffer
        self._run_callback(callback, self._consume(num_bytes))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 230, in _run_callback
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/stack_context.py", line 173, in wrapped
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/websocket.py", line 183, in _on_frame_type
        self.stream.read_until("\xff", self._on_end_delimiter)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 133, in read_until
        if self._read_from_buffer():`

// Loop back to start (line 325 in iostream)

Any help?????? 
Im using the pypi tornado 
1.2.1, tornadIO 0.0.4, zeromq 2.1.4, and pypi pyzmq, on ubuntu linux

Edit:
It seems to originate from this snippet in my on_close() handler:

`if self._client_sub and self._client_sub.stream:
    try:
        self._client_sub.stream.stop_on_recv()
        self._client_sub.stream.stop_on_err()`

```
except Exception, e:
    logging.error("Failed to close stream and sub socket on client disconnect", exc_info=True)
```

and here is the traceback:

`[E 110425 20:52:50 messgr:202] Failed to close stream and sub socket on client disconnect
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "messgr.py", line 198, in on_close
        try:
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stream'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/init.py", line 776, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/init.py", line 654, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/tornado/options.py", line 362, in format
    record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/init.py", line 416, in formatException
    traceback.print_exception(ei[0], ei[1], ei[2], None, sio)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/traceback.py", line 125, in print_exception
    print_tb(tb, limit, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/traceback.py", line 69, in print_tb
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/linecache.py", line 14, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/linecache.py", line 40, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)`

What happens is that traceback happens one. Then it seems to stack, and happen twice, and then 3 times...endlessly.

Comment: I found some more log. It seems to originate with this snippet from my on_close() handler:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems very similar to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/6f7d121af73fbc77/b568262152372120?lnk=gst&q=exception#b568262152372120) issue

Comment: Yea sorry I realized that it did get resolved with the author of the library. So I will mark this as an answer :-)

Comment: Maybe because it wasnt an answer, but more of a comment?